# Inverse limit and graded functor commute?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, derived-functors

I am trying to understand a proof where there are graded algebras and inverse limit involved.

In one of the steps it seems to commute this two elements. Is there any reference where this is stated.

$$\varprojlim (gr(\Lambda^*_n))=gr(\varprojlim \Lambda_n^*).$$

Where $\Lambda^*_n$ stands for the shifted symmetric polynomials of $n$ indeterminates.

Note that the inverse limit $\varprojlim \Lambda_n^* = \Lambda^*$ is taken in the category of filtered algebras.

[MSE QUESTION HERE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254397/inverse-limit-and-graded-functor-commute)

Comment: This seems rather similar to your question on Mathematics: [inverse limit and graded functor commute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3254397). I think that [this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638) provides reasonable guidelines on [meta-tag:cross-posting], probably one of the most important things is to link each copy to the other ones.

Comment: Oh! Hate when people is more worried about format than Maths. I do it to get more people involved. Anything else. I think that is not a big trouble to post it in both sites. Spending the time on looking if I post it in other site or not I think is not what people should do when they join a MATHS EXCHANGE site.

Comment: By "shifted polynomial algebra" you mean the exterior algebra?

Comment: Filtered by degree or by order?

Comment: @MarcoFarinati I define $\Lambda^*$ as the inverse limit of $\Lambda_n^*$ in the category of filtered algebras. It is graded by degree, i.e. $\Lambda_n^*=\cup_k (\Lambda_n^*)^k$. Here, each $(\Lambda_n^*)^k$ is the algebra containing all shifted symmetric polynomials in $n$ indeterminates and with terms with degree lower or equal to $k$.